# How can I replace a switch in Java with a list that references a variable for each case?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, hash, switch-statement

I was unable to find a prior question like this here (which surprises me), so..

I have a working Java program where part of it analyzes typed input. Some input 'options' are the strings in the cases below.

```
switch (varName.toLowerCase())  {
    case "steps":
        common.steps = true;
        break;
    case "scale":
        common.scale = true;
        break;
    case "float":
        common.fracts = false;
        break;
    case "fraction":
        common.fracts = true;
        break;
    case "spaces":
        common.spaces = false;
        break;
    ... etc.
}
```

In C or C++, I could shorten this code by making a list (which is a structure containing a string name and a variable pointer) such as

```
LIST varAction[] = { { "steps", &common.steps },
                     { "scale", &common.scale },
                     .. etc.
                   };
```

and then simply checking in a loop with i = 0 thru size of the list

```
if ( strcmp(varAction[i].name, input) == 0)  {
    *varAction[i].pointer = condition;
}
```

The Java switch occurs more than once and is a maintenance problem, which is why I want a better way.

I could use a hashed index into an array using the hash of the string, but that would prevent me from using the specific variable names thru the code as needed, making that code less clear... i.e. I don't want to do (pseudo-code)

```
hashTable[varName] instead of (for example)  

if ( common.fracts )
     { do something }
```

There must be a better way? Is there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I missing something? It sounds to me like a ´Map<String, Boolean>` will accomplish what you want. Use a HashMap for implementation.

Comment: @OleV.V.: That was my reaction as well, but the OP said he/she doesn't want to use strings everywhere he/she is referring to these properties

Comment: FWIW, you can usually fix the need for switches using polymorphism or design-by-contract (interfaces) to encapsulate whatever your switch statements are doing. That way the behavior is intrinsic to the object's type, and the problem is then reduced to selecting the right concrete class to instantiate.

Comment: @AndrewC - yes, I hinted at that somewhere in here. A good idea for a new design of something else, but too much work for this one. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

From your question, it's fairly clear that you know you can't do what you've said you'd do in C/C++, but just for others coming to the question: Java doesn't have references to variables.

It's tempting to push the question out a level: Look at why you have `varName` in the first place and see if you can avoid it.

> The Java switch occurs more than once and is a maintenance problem, which is why I want a better way.

That suggests that `common` should have accessor function(s) for this information, so the switch exists only in one place (the getter) or two places (the getter and the setter).

```
void setThingy(String name, boolean value) {
    switch (name.toLowerCase())  {
        case "steps":
            this.steps = value;
            break;
        case "scale":
            this.scale = value;
            break;
        case "float":
            this.fracts = value;
            break;
        case "fraction":
            this.fracts = value;
            break;
        case "spaces":
            this.spaces = value;
            break;
        // ... etc.
    }
}

boolean getThingy(String name) {
    switch (name.toLowerCase())  {
        case "steps":
            return common.steps;
        case "scale":
            return common.scale;
        case "float":
            return this.fracts;
        case "fraction":
            return this.fracts;
        case "spaces":
            return this.spaces;
        // ... etc.
    }
}
```

If `common`'s class isn't something you can change, a static utility function somewhere would also work, but better if it's in the class if possible.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder,  I've done just that in other cases but it probably ends up unsightly in this case - my fault for not being clear that with the variables used so frequently in many source files, it would make code less clear by using the function. I think I read something once about an Interface being used to do this too but I can't see the benefit vs. development overhead & loss of clarity.

Comment: Depending on the origin of the string with the "property" name, I would go even further and use an `enum` type instead of strings.

Comment: Thanks @TJ,  this seems for now to be the most practical.. because I realized I only need the "put" part.. the vars are already used as needed. But I think some combination of that and a hash map will do it later on.

Answer (score 4):

With Java 8+ you could use something like:

```
Map<String, Runnable> actions = new HashMap<> ();
actions.put("steps", () -> common.steps = true);
actions.put("scale", () -> common.scales = true);
//etc.
```

then in your code:

```
actions.get(varName.toLowerCase()).run(); //need null check
```

You could do it with Java 7- too using anonymous classes but it would be more verbose.

Comment: Certainly easier to look at than a switch.

Comment: This is the hash idea I originally had but I wasn't sure it's the best way. I'm starting to think it may be.  Except one thing: for all I know in Java, I'm not familiar with the syntax you used for the key value.. the part  " () -> ..."  What are the parens and the arrow?

Comment: You could also do it with classes. As value in Hashtable use: Class<? extends BaseFragment>. And then in the put statement use ActionFragment.class as value. Instantiate with .getConstructor().newInstance()

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an option, developing my idea from the comment just a little bit. Not sure whether you will like it, I’d like to offer it in case.

```
public class Common {

    private Map<String, Boolean> options = new HashMap<>();

    public void setOption(String varName, boolean condition) {
        options.put(varName.toLowerCase(), condition);
    }

    public boolean isSteps() { return options.get("steps"); }
    public boolean isFracts() { return options.get("fractions"); }
    public boolean isScale() { return options.get("scale"); }

}
```

You may want to put in some defense, for instance to avoid setting non-existing options.

Edit: Drawing on David Foerster’s comments on enums, here’s a solution using them:

```
public enum Option {

    steps, scale, fraction;

    private boolean option = false;

    public static void setOption(String varName, boolean condition) {
        valueOf(varName.toLowerCase()).option = condition;
    }

    public boolean isSet() {
        return option;
    }

}
```

Now the lookup happens in the setter, not in the getter. Defence against setting non-existing options is built-in: you will get an exception if you try, this behaviour can of course be modified if you prefer. The solution is quite extensible, it’s easy to add more enum constants if the need arises.

Comment: An interesting possibility too.

Comment: Depending on the origin of the string with the "property" name, I would go even further and use an `enum` type instead of strings which allows the use of `EnumSet` – with far less overhead than `HashMap<String, Boolean>`. You can also derive the appropriate enum value with the `#valueOf(String)` class method.

Comment: The enum approach certainly has some advantages. Each enum instance could even have the boolean value inside of it, so you could do `if (Options.steps.isSet())` with no lookup. And the defence against setting non-existing options is built-in.

Comment: Enum constants should be uppercase by convention.

Comment: @shmosel, correct. So we need `.toUpperCase()` rather than`.toLowerCase()` in `setOption()`.

Answer (score 1):

*Warning: It's been a while since I last wrote some Java, and this is probably against best practices, so continue with care! Also it's [just a quick and dirty example](http://ideone.com/PGfLbz), I wrote this on a (not up to date) mobile phone...*

You could try to use reflection:

```
class Common {
  public boolean a;
  public boolean b;
  public boolean tryToSet(String field, boolean value) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Class<?> cl = this.getClass();
    try {
      Field f = cl.getDeclaredField(field);
      f.setBoolean(this, value);
      return true;
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Returning a boolean gives you the possibility to implement a "default case":

```
if (! c.tryToSet("x", false)) {
  System.out.println("some default case");
}
```

Comment: Now all we need is a JNI solution.

Comment: Thanks @Danier Jour.  In my early days of Java (1999) I did this kind of thing to write a generic field filler. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCases 
{
    static boolean steps = false;
    static boolean fracts;
    static boolean scale;

    public static void  main( String[] args ) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println( "Type the input" );
        String typedInput = input.nextLine();

        Object[][] tests = { { "steps", steps }, { "float", fracts }, { "scale", scale } };

        for( int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++ )
        {
            if( typedInput.equals( tests[ i ][ 0 ] ) )
            {
                tests[ i ][ 1 ] = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++ )
        {
            for( int j = 0; j < tests[ i ].length; j++ )
            {
                    System.out.print( tests[ i ][ j ] + " " );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    }

}
```

All necessary conversions are automatically done.

Comment: Thanks - I never thought to make it all Object type. very close to hash logic but simpler. The code works.

Comment: I am glad it works for you. Can you mark it as an answer? Or vote it up so other people can see it.

Comment: It doesn’t work for me? I enter `steps`. The loop in the end prints that steps is true (as expected), but the `steps` variable declared in the beginning is still `false`.

Comment: Sure @funaquarius24 but I'm new here and not sure I did it right. If you dont see it, let me know or tell me how.

Comment: When you put `steps` (with the value false) into `tests`, it gets automatically converted to a reference to `Boolean.FALSE` that is stored in the Object array. When in the loop you set `tests[i][1] = true`, the reference in the array is changed to `Boolean.TRUE`, but the original `boolean steps` remains unchanged. So referring to it in `if (steps)` won’t work as desired.

Comment: No the initial declarations only assist in population the array because we want both the String and boolean to be saved together. in order to get your value, you have to use `tests[ i ][ j ]` directly or declare a new variable and assign `tests[ i ][ j ]` to it.